# Order of resources in a class using ensure_packages

Tags: puppet

I have a puppet class that uses the apt library and puppet's stdlib, this is the code:

```
class mymodule::gcc_48
{
  if $::lsbdistrelease == 12.04 {

    include apt
    apt::ppa { 'ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test': }
    ensure_packages( ['gcc-4.8', 'g++-4.8'] )

    exec { 'update_alternatives_gcc':
      command => '/usr/sbin/update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 50',
      creates => '/etc/alternatives/gcc'
    }

    exec { 'update_alternatives_gpp':
      command => '/usr/sbin/update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8 50',
      creates => '/etc/alternatives/g++'
    }
  }
}
```

I need puppet to do all of these things in the order it's written (well, except for the last two exec) but it's not clear to me how to write the dependency relationship that includes ensure_packages. I tried using the ordering arrows (->) but these don't work with functions (i.e. with ensure_packages).

As written, the resources are applied all out of order and it takes several runs of puppet for everything to work.

I want to try to keep all of this code in the same class if that's possible.

Comment: Could you please explain what the process you need arrange. Do you mean you need: install module `apt`, then check the class apt::ppa, then confirm if package `gcc-4.8` and `g++-4.8` is installed or not? Why you need `ensure_packages` by this way? the better way is, set base.pp, `include base`, then put all packages, such as apt, gcc-4.8, g++-4.8 in `base` in base.pp  directly.

Comment: ensure_packages as an stdlib function that declares the resources to install the named packages if and only if they aren't already declared.  I need to do it in this order because: the commands can't run until the packages are installed and the packages can't be installed until the custom ppa is added to the system.  I'm sorry but I don't understand how adding a base.pp helps exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my understand. Set the class `apt::ppa` as below:

```
apt::ppa { 'ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test': 
    # Here puts your code for this class apt::ppa,
    before => Package['gcc-4.8', 'g++-4.8']
}
```

I recommend to go through this document: [Learning Puppet — Resource Ordering](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/ordering.html)

Comment: Thanks!  And the exec commands get a 'require' on those packages too i guess.

Comment: If you need that order, you can add.